# CSH - check if variable is integer or not

Tags: unix, scripting, csh

Have tried this, but then even though i put a number as $3, it still goes in the "not numeric" statement

```
if ($#argv == 3) then
   if ( $3 !~ '^[0-9]+$' ) then
      echo "Not numeric"
      exit 1
   else
      echo "Numeric"
   endif 
endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Obligatory "don't use csh" links - http://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html and http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt

That said, your problem is that you have single quoted the regex pattern. Changing it to this should work:

```
if ( $3 !~ ^[0-9]+$ ) then
```

Comment: To avoid badly formed number error, should it be `if ( "$3" !~ "^[0-9]+$ ") then` ?

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that there are better ways (the `($3 !~ ^[0-9]+$)` does not work for me) but I use this:

```
echo "$3" | awk '{print $1+0}'
```

*The "trick" is in `$1+0` (no quotes!) where you force awk to interpret $1 as a number.*

**Note:**
If yow want to know if a non-numeric value is inputed, then use this:

```
echo "$3" | awk '{if ($1 ~ /^[0]+$/) {print "0"} else {if ($1+0 == 0) {print "Not a number"} else {print $1+0} }}'
```

Comment: To catch a 0.00 type input, change the pattern /^[0]+$/ to /^0[.]*[0]+$/

Answer (score 0):

none of the above recommendations worked for me, so I used the "$?" variable to make it work.  This could definitely be improved on, to filter for non-alpha characters as well, but my this is intended for internal use so I think filtering for alpha characters is good enough.

set ans = $<

set result = `echo "$ans" |  grep -Eo '[a-zA-Z ]{1,100}'`

if ( "$?" ==  "0" ) then

```
echo -n "input must only contain digits"

echo ""
```

exit 0

endif

set result = `echo "$ans" |  grep -Eo '[0-9]{1,10}'`

if ( "$?" ==  "0" ) then

```
       echo -n "Your input is $result"

       echo ""
```

else

echo "Input is not an acceptable number"

endif